# Google Cloud SQL cross regional replication for selected schemas

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is it be possible to create Google Cloud SQL Postgres  [cross-region](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication#cross-region-read-replicas) replication only for selected schemas in the database?

Answer (score 0):

[A replica is a copy of the instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/replication/create-replica#:%7E:text=A%20read%20replica%20is%20a%20copy%20of%20the%20primary%20instance%20), not of separated parts of it. So what you are asking is not possible, you can only do a replica of the full instance, no matter if it’s cross-region or in-region.